# Are multiple OpenSSL Bio objects needed to allow parallel requests?

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm using **OpenSSL's BIO** API to send HTTPS requests. I need to send 2+ requests **at the same time** (not serially) to the same destination via **HTTP/1.1** over an **non-blocking socket**.

I have requests working, but they are sent/processed *serially*, not *simultaneously*.

For example, currently, *when using one Bio object* and sending multiple requests at the same moment to a mocked API that has a built-in 5 sec delay before it sends a response, I receive the responses after 5 sec, 10 sec, 15 sec, 20 sec, etc. Indicating requests are processed serially.  (The server can handle and respond to multiple requests from different clients with a consistent 5 sec delay, confirming this is client code related.)

Question:

- Do I need to use one Bio object `BIO* bio;` per request that I want to send simultaneously? Or is there a different way to use Bio to send and process the requests simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The BIO objects have the same thread safety as the [SSL](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/) objects.  i.e. a single SSL context is NOT thread safe.  You can have multiple SSL contexts running at the same time but not within the same SSL context.

So if you truly need to have multiple HTTPS request in flight at the same time, you need to have multiple sockets (one for each simultaneous request).  Each socket will have it's own SSL context and it's own BIO context.

I simple implementation would be a socket per thread.  A better (and maybe a more complex one) would be a socket per CPU where you have some way to serialise the access to the SSL context so that they don't overlap (e.g. boost asio strand per ssl stream)

Comment: The app is single threaded. OpenSSL's bio creates the sockets. My understanding is that you're suggesting a new BIO and new SSL context per simultaneous request desired.

Comment: There are lots of different types of BIO's.  File, Memory, Sockets, etc. In boost asio it only uses a memory BIO per socket and uses it's own socket code.  Yes a socket BIO creates a socket.  And yes I am suggesting a socket (using BIO's or any other socket types) with a SSL  context per simultaneous request desired.  If you don't then you can't send simultaneous requests on a single https connection because http/1.1 does not allow it.

Comment: Right, fortunately Bio automatically creates the appropriate type (socket) depending on the type of sink (network). It definitely sounds like from you that a Bio can support at most one simultaneous request, which is what I was trying to determine, how to best use Bio's API. I'm going to test this with multiple bios and one SSL context, and again with multiple bios with multiple SSL contexts; I thought I read in the OpenSSL docs that only one SSL context is required, which contradicts a part of the answer. But I'll update here. Thanks.